# Address of memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory-address

In this code,

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
printf("a = %p, &a = %p\n", a, &a);
```

same address for `a` and `&a` is printed. As I know, `a` is a const pointer to 0th element of array. Why address of `a` and contents of it are equal?

Comment: When you use `%p` specification then do not forget to cast the argument to `void *`: `printf("a = %p, &a = %p\n", (void *)a, (void *)&a)`.

Comment: `a` is not a const pointer; it is an array. Have a look at the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why address of a and contents of it are equal?*

They are not.

In most of the cases, a variable of type array decays to a pointer to the first element. Thus

```
printf("1. %p, 2. %p", (void*)a, (void *)&a[0]);
```

will print same values.

That said, the address of an array, is the same as the address of the first element of the array, thus

```
 printf("1. %p, 2. %p", (void*)a, (void*)&a);
```

also prints the same *value*. However, remember, they are not of the same type.

- `a`, which is same as `&a[0]` in this case, is of type `int *`
- `&a`, is of type `int *[5]`, i.e, a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s.

Comment: How a is stored in memory? Any pointer variable, is 4 (or 8) byte in memory, with value = address of variable that pointer points to. Is it incorrect about array name?

Comment: @yousefrashidi it is not stored in memory at all. C.f. *"How is the address of `int a` stored in memory?! Doesn't every `int a` actually need 12 bytes of memory, 4 for the `a` and 8 for its address?!" And where is this address stored?" Pointers all way down...*